# I am getting warning during installtion of laravel mix

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel,today I am following laravel mix topic.According to the documentation a single line(npm install) install laravel mix on exiting project.But,I am getting a error continuously,i added the error screenshot.Please help me to solve the issue.Thanks in advance.

[image: Npm install problem]

Comment: Could you post your package.json file here?

Comment: Adam thank you very much for your response,here is my packge.json  file.

https://jsonblob.com/ff5b8b65-6346-11e8-ae7e-17a53dc6796a

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your package-lock.json and re-run `npm install`

Comment: Thanks it solve after using npm cache clean --force,this command.

Comment: Awesome, glad to be of assistance. If you could accept this answer, that would be great. Happy coding.